# Junit4 : expected=Exception not working with SPRING

Tags: java, spring, junit

I'm trying to use the @Test(expected = RuntimeException.class) annotation in
order to test for an expected exception.  My code is as follows:

```
@Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
    public void testSaveThrowsRuntimeException(){

                    User user = domain.save(null);

    }
```

and my save method simple like this :

```
public User save(User newUser) { 
         if(newUser == null) { 
            throw new RuntimeException(); 
         }
         //saving code goes here
    }
```

after debugging the code I found that code throwing the exception as expected but its getting eaten somewhere in between in spring framework classes.

I tried the same with old way (try catch block) but still I am not able to catch that exception in test and test keeps throwing errors in runafter method of Junit :

```
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException
at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1031)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:709)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:678)
at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener$TransactionContext.endTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:504)
at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.endTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:277)
at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:170)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:344)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runAfters(SpringMethodRoadie.java:307)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie$RunBeforesThenTestThenAfters.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:338)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runWithRepetitions(SpringMethodRoadie.java:217)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTest(SpringMethodRoadie.java:197)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:143)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:142)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:45)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException
at org.objectweb.jotm.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:245)
at org.objectweb.jotm.Current.commit(Current.java:488)
at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1028)
... 23 more
```

And I am sure this is because of that RuntimeException I am throwing in save but not able catch it or pass the test with expected clause.

anybody have any idea whats going wrong?

Comment: If Spring will always catch the exception, why do you want to test for it not doing so? Isn't this the expected behaviour (even if not what *you* were expecting)

Comment: yes thats true but it throws error on console afterward. So I want catch it myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a work-around I found to with Junit 4.5 - separate the @Transactional and @ExpectedException into nested functions.
I guess the problem is something to do with the aop stuff spring puts around a @Transactional method.

```
@Test
@ExpectedException(org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
public void Test10UniqueName()
{
    DoTest10UniqueName();
}

@Transactional
public void DoTest10UniqueName()
{
    final String NAME = "NAME";
    ProductCategoryDAO dao = DAOFactory.getProductCategoryDAO();
    ProductCategory test1 = new ProductCategory();
    test1.setName(NAME);
    ProductCategory test2 = new ProductCategory();
    test2.setName(NAME);
    dao.save(test1);
    dao.save(test2);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Turned out that my first answer was wrong. Both @Test(expected=...) and @ExpectedException work, but there is some incompability between [the Spring TestContext and Junit 4.5](http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-5145). Using Junit 4.4 solved the problem for me. Finally.

Answer (score 1):

Either you're running a unit test, in which case Spring TX shouldn't come in to play, or you're running some kind of integration test where you want to test what the save method does when your runtime exception *is* swallowed. I don't think anything is going wrong, you just need to make sure you understand what it is you are trying to test.

Comment: thank you Paul, if you look at the stack trace, I am running tests  with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner, so Spring TX comes in play.

It works with @NotTransactional annotation.

Comment: Well, exactly. Either run it with plain old junit and not with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner and test for runtime exception, or test for expected transactional behaviour.